# Why am I experiencing water shortages when I have adequate capacity?

Tags: cities-skylines

Why is this happening?

I have more than enough capacity, the area is clearly covered by pipes, and yet these buildings are being abandoned due to lack of water.

This is only occurring after I resumed my saved game, but even with fast-forward time it doesn't resolve itself, it continues to worsen.

I have tried reloading multiple times, same result.

Edit: I thought I fixed it by adding additional power, didn't work, still getting this all over the map (second screen shot).

[image: Lack of Water]

[image: Lack of Water 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due to budget constraints.  Make sure you have adequate day/night budget for water and power.  They could make this more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your water network may be seperated into multiple isolated networks with differing supply. The statistic counts overall supply and demand, but water doesn't automatically balance between networks. You need to add connecting pipes for it to do that.

Comment: This was due to inadequate budget for water during the day/night cycle on the budget tab.  They should make it more clear that it is due to funding, and not related to supply.

Answer (score 0):

I know this wasn't OP's problem, but...

Sometimes power lines go down. I swear they go down all by themselves, but they're very easy to cut while laying down roads, cemetaries, etc. Any water facilities fed by them also go down.

I learned to simply put a windmill next to my water facilities!